# /Pointwise2022.2.1/linux_x86_64/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set error

Tags: installation, grid, updates, ubuntu-18.04, issue-tracking

I am trying to install Pointwise 2022 on my computer with Ubuntu 18.04 and getting the following error

symbol lookup error: /home/django/Fidelity/Pointwise/Pointwise2022.2.1/linux_x86_64/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

I tried updating libfreetype based on the previous answers on internet but didn't work. I have tried most of the solutions given on the internet to resolve this issue, but still unable to do so. Your help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks.